# gnuplot time axis from two different columns

Tags: time, format, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot some data from a four columns file. The first one is the numbre of data the second one is the year the third one are months and the final one are values of temperature. The thing is that I woul like that my x axis takes a date from the second and the third columns.
The text file look like this:

1      1990         2                  265.78945923
2      1990         3                  260.53842163
3      1990         4                  265.00366211
4      1990         5                  277.61206055
5      1990         6                  284.72595215
6      1990         7                  291.54879761
7      1990         8                  293.61392212
8      1990         9                  288.47149658
9      1990        10                  284.55172729
12     1991         1                  285.98762388
13     1991         2                  283.47484293

I'm using a code like this:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y %m'
plot 'datafile' u 2:4
```

But it doesn't work. I woul like to have on my x axis the year and the months.
All help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me (tested with 5.0 and 4.2.6). Do you get an error message?

Comment: Hello. There's no error message. I'm using 5.0.   I get on my x axis hours instead of years and no data is plotted

Comment: Now is working. It was something with set format x "%Y"

Comment: But you don't have the months, do you?